# comma separated parametrized maven ONLY tests one testng file

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am facing an issue with Maven which nowhere on internet I could find an answer for it. appreciate if anyone can help me with it. I aiming to test 2 testng files sent as parameter to POM as:

```
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFiles=1.xml,2.xml
```

and the POM file is:

```
<plugins>
        <!-- Following plugin executes the testng tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Compiler plugin configures the java version to be usedfor compiling 
            the code -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

but, when i run, it ONLY runs the 2.xml file and runs it twice!!!

tried many options but no matter what is the second xml file it totally ignores the first and runs the second one twice.

can anyone please help?

thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on what other options you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your surefire plugin should look like below

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>${file}</suiteXmlFiles>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Pay close attention to `<suiteXmlFiles>${file}</suiteXmlFiles>`

So now you can pass in multiple suite files via

```
mvn clean test -Dfile=src/test/resources/suite-one-with-execution.xml, src/test/resources/suite-two-with-execution.xml
```

For more details you can refer to my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/parallel-execution-of-multiple-testng-suites/).

Comment: Thanks Krishnan, 
i tried your suggestion, but the problem still persists. basically, doesnt matter what comes before "," it only runs the testng file after "," and runs it twice.
Is there any other solution for it? also tried different versions of surefire

Comment: @reza - Can you please try once using the surefire plugin version `2.15` and see? I would like to figure out what has broken here because if you take a look at the blog post i shared, its a working example. Also please ensure that you are using the latest version of TestNG viz., `6.13.1` (at this moment)

Comment: just tried again, same result, its so weird, i had some this before too, but have no idea why this project can't
I'm using 
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8</version>
    <scope>compile</scope></dependency>
and 2.15 for surefire

Answer (score 0):

finally understood where the issue was, for some reason i still dont know why, the Suite name in xml files should be not same as each other!!